# Value not assigning to variable? C calculator

Tags: c, calculator

I am trying to create a simple calculator in C. I have only one issue currently, that is that when I try and assign my operator value to the value inputted, stored in a array of characters, it assigns it, but when I exit the for loop is no longer assigned. I have tried using malloc, but this does not work. Thanks in advance

```
int calculator()
{
int exit;
exit = 1;
while(exit == 1){

    printf("Welcome to the calculator, please enter the calculation you wish to make, if you wish to exit type EXIT\n");

    float num1;
    float num2;
    char operation;
    float ans;
    char string[10];
    int beenhere = 0;

    scanf("%s", &string);
    int result = strncmp(string, "EXIT", 10);

    if(result == 0){
        exit = 0;
    }
    else{
        int length = strlen(string);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i <= length; i++){
            if(isdigit(string[i]) != 0){
                if(beenhere == 0){
                    num1 = (float)string[i] - '0';
                    beenhere = 1;
                }
                else{
                    num2 = (float)string[i] - '0';
                }
            }
            else{
                operation = string[i];
            }
        }
        printf("num1 %f\n", num1);
        printf("%c\n", operation);
        printf("num2 %f\n", num2);

        if(operation == '+'){
            ans = num1 + num2;
        }
        if(operation == '-'){
            ans = num1 - num2;
        }
        if(operation == '/'){
            ans = num1 / num2;
        }
        if(operation == '*'){
            ans = num1 * num2;
        }
        if(operation == '^'){
            ans = (float)pow(num1,num2);
        }

        printf("Your answer is %f\n", ans);

        }
}
return 0;
```

}

EDIT: I am referring to the forloop, where the assignment is: operation = string[i];

Comment: which loop you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the for loop:

```
    for(i = 0; i <= length; i++){
```

Since length is `strlen(..)`, you cannot got to length, but to `length-1`.

You are doing an extra loop, which is with a char of 0, setting your instruction to that null value - ie empty string.

Change your loop to:

```
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
```

Comment: Those are always the difficult-to-spot ones!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
    for(i = 0; i <= length; i++)
```

to

```
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
```